# How could I overcome tensorflow-gpu import error?

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

I'm new tensorflow programming.  We have RTX2080 TI GPU in the workstation.
Win 10 64 bit OS installed on it. I'm using Pycharm Community Edition 3.1 edıtor

I researched from the net(also from this similar questions) and  I set up following versions  below:

Cuda 10.00
Cudnn v7.6.2.24
Python 3.6
Tensorflow-gpu 1.14.0

Unfortunately when I run this command:

```
import tensorflow as tf
```

Pycharm gave this error into the python console:

```
 traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2019.3.1\plugins\python-ce\helpers\pydev\_pydev_bundle\pydev_umd.py", line 197, in runfile
    pydev_imports.execfile(filename, global_vars, local_vars)  # execute the script
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2019.3.1\plugins\python-ce\helpers\pydev\_pydev_imps\_pydev_execfile.py", line 18, in execfile
    exec(compile(contents+"\n", file, 'exec'), glob, loc)
  File "C:/Users/5G/Desktop/OFDM_DNN-master/OFDM_DNN-master/DNN_Detection/OFDM_ChannelEstimation_DeepLearning_QAM_random_pilot.py", line 5, in <module>
    import tensorflow as tf
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2019.3.1\plugins\python-ce\helpers\pydev\_pydev_bundle\pydev_import_hook.py", line 21, in do_import
    module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\5G\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 28, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow  # pylint: disable=unused-import
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2019.3.1\plugins\python-ce\helpers\pydev\_pydev_bundle\pydev_import_hook.py", line 21, in do_import
    module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\5G\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\tensorflow\python\__init__.py", line 52, in <module>
    from tensorflow.core.framework.graph_pb2 import *
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2019.3.1\plugins\python-ce\helpers\pydev\_pydev_bundle\pydev_import_hook.py", line 21, in do_import
    module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\5G\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\tensorflow\core\framework\graph_pb2.py", line 7, in <module>
    from google.protobuf import descriptor as _descriptor
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2019.3.1\plugins\python-ce\helpers\pydev\_pydev_bundle\pydev_import_hook.py", line 21, in do_import
    module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\5G\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\google\protobuf\descriptor.py", line 47, in <module>
    from google.protobuf.pyext import _message
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2019.3.1\plugins\python-ce\helpers\pydev\_pydev_bundle\pydev_import_hook.py", line 21, in do_import
 
module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
ImportError: DLL load failed: Belirtilen yordam bulunamadı.
```

How could I overcome these errors? Which versions of Phyton, Cuda,cuDNN, tensorflow-gpu are compatible with each other?

Would you give me advices please??

Comment: Your traceback is incomplete.

Comment: what means your traceback is incomplete? Would you clarify these ? what is my fault which program am i have to install more??

Comment: What you copied from the python console is called traceback (it starts with Traceback (most recent call last): ), and you did not copy it completely, it does onw show the actual error. We cannot help you until you provide the full traceback.

Comment: I would recommend you to run this code outside of PyCharm, as its interferring, and then reposting the traceback.  Also make sure that the error messages are in English so we can understand them.

Answer (score 2):

Have you used the command prompt in administrator mode?

Use the below command:

```
pip3 install --upgrade tensorflow-gpu
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem just as:

Set up tensorflow -gpu 1.5

after downgrade protobuf 3.6.0 just as:

```
 pip install protobuf==3.6.0
```

İt worked!!